# How to use angular-translate in HTML tag property as a function param

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

We have this:

```
<td ... ng-click="someFunction(param)" ...></td>
```

The function is defined in one of the controllers in controllers.js:

```
$scope.someFunction= function (param) { ... }
```

and the param is expected to be translated string. I tried different approaches, e.g.:

```
<td ... ng-click="someFunction('PARAM_TRANSLATION_KEY' | translate)" ...></td>
```

or:

```
<td ... ng-click="someFunction({{'PARAM_TRANSLATION_KEY' | translate}})" ...></td>
```

and also others, but nothing seems to be working and I couldn't find this in the angular-translate documentation and/or I-net.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

angular translate has a translation service that you can use inside your js code ,

https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate

simply pass the function as

```
ng-click="someFunction('PARAM_TRANSLATION_KEY')
```

and use the service inside the function like so:

```
function(param) {  $translate(param).then(translation) { ... } }
```

**UPDATE** : if you cant change the code then you can pass the param like so

1. Add the service to the scope so you can access it
2. Use the service to translate and call your function after callback

Example:

```js
var translations = {
  HEADLINE: 'What an awesome module!',
  PARAGRAPH: 'Srsly!',
  NAMESPACE: {
    PARAGRAPH: 'And it comes with awesome features!'
  }
};

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

app.config(['$translateProvider',
  function($translateProvider) {
    // add translation table
    $translateProvider
      .translations('en', translations)
      .preferredLanguage('en');
  }
]);


app.controller('myController', function($scope, $translate) {
  $scope.translationServiceCallback = function(param, cb) {
    $translate(param).then(function(translation) {
      cb(translation);
    });
  }

  $scope.log = function(param) {
    console.log(param)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate/2.11.1/angular-translate.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
      <button ng-click="translationServiceCallback('HEADLINE',log)">Translate</button>
      <button ng-click="log('HEADLINE')">WYSIWYG</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't change the function code and even if I could, there are other places in the code that invoke the function with already translated param, so this will not work - the param value needs to be translated, before it was passed to the function ...

Comment: then you can pass the service, and use it to pass the param (Look update)

Comment: since the translation service returns a promise and not the value you need to use the function inside a callback

Comment: i have to correct something, angular does not support passing anonymous functions from the html so you need to define a function to call the callback